# How to Ensemble LGBM and XGBoost Machine Learning Models?

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, regression, dataframe

I want to Ensemble my predictions for the StratifiedKFold of LGBM and XGBoost into another LGBM Model. I had written the following code which works when the data set has an ID_COL, but in this data set I don't have any ID_COL. It is simply based on the index. How can I ensemble the model in such case?

The Train and Test data are stored in `train` and `test` file respectively.

**CODE**

```
train_new = train[[TARGET_COL]]

test_new = test[[ID_COL]] #ID_COL is not available in data.

train_new['lgb'] = lgb_oofs
test_new['lgb'] = lgb_preds

train_new['xgb'] = xgb_oofs
test_new['xgb'] = xgb_preds
```

After this I pass `train_new` and `test_new` to a LGBM Model.

Comment: you want two ensemble 2 gradient boosting with another gradietn boosting? So the ensembler only sees two columns with the predictions/

Comment: There are many way to ensemble (voting, bagging, boosting)? Please be more specific.